# Linux shell script to copy last lines of a file in a directory to append to a file in another directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have written the below shell script to copy the last lines of a file in a directory to append to a file in another directory

```
cd /opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/Lg2Logs
GrinderLG1='rm101sys1lweb22'
GrinderLg2='rm101sys1lweb23'
fileCount=$(ls -l|wc -l)
echo $fileCount
for (( c=0; c<=$fileCount-2; c++ ))
do
      Lines=$(more $GrinderLg2"-"$c"-data.log"|wc -l)
      Lines1=`expr $Lines - 1`
      `"tail -"$Lines1"f /opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/Lg2Logs/"$GrinderLg2"-"$c"-data.log>>/opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/"$GrinderLG1"-"$c"-data.log"`
      #exec $command
done
```

When I am executing this script it says no such file or directory at tail command. Actually both the files exist. Please help.

Comment: i have answered your problem. If it does not work for you then inform me.

Comment: Tried with the changes you mentioned but am getting the command only till >>.

Comment: It is tailing the first file only but not appending to the destination file.

Comment: Its working. When executed the shells script with -x option it was showing the command till >> only but appened to the files as expected. Thanks a lot Mr.32.

Answer (score 0):

```
  `"tail -"$Lines1"f /opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/Lg2Logs/"$GrinderLg2"-"$c"-data.log>>/opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/"$GrinderLG1"-"$c"-data.log"`
```

change to

```
  tail -"$Lines1"f /opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/Lg2Logs/"$GrinderLg2"-"$c"-data.log>>/opt/grinder/svn/IAVS/GrinderLogs/GrinderBaseLogs/"$GrinderLG1"-"$c"-data.log
```

should work.

---

In my setup i have tested as below way

```
#!/bin/sh
`"tail -10f filename"`
```

give error filename not found

But

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -10f filename
```

This works fine.